# <Exercise_2.Line object at 0x7ff1ddbfeba8> in bash what does it mean? linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, oop

I wrote a code that should return me the equation of a line passing through two points and it works but in the bash it also appears this line and I don't know what it could mean. The code is saved as Exercise_2.py and there are two classes in it (Point and Line).

This is my code:

class Point:

```
def __init__(self,x,y,):

    self.x=x
    self.y=y
```

class Line:

```
def __init__(self,m,q,):

    self.m=m
    self.q=q

    print(f"y={m}x+{q}")
```

This is what I see if I run the code:

y=3x+2

< Exercise_2.Line object at 0x7ff1ddbfeba8 >

Thanks to whoever will explain it to me and thanks for your time.

P.S. maybe I'm finding the problem. I should use the **repr** method but I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: Can you please include a bit more of your code? A large enough sample size for us to reproduce your problem is often helpful.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you seem to be passing a Line object to print. What you see in the last line is the string representation of that object. As @Axe319 pointed out, you need to show the complete code.

Comment: but it's the complete code

Comment: all I wrote is from "class point" to the print function

Comment: if you do something  like `print(Line(3,2))` you will get the output you are describing. The reason you are getting this output is because you are printing the class object and instantiating it. This causes the __init__ function to be run but also prints out the object representation.


if you want to simply create an instance of the class, you can do so with `test = Line(3, 2)`. I'm guessing that is the output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a class to the print function it prints that object's representation. You can modify what displays when you print it by adding a `__repr__` method to your class and returning a string.

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self,m,q):

        self.m=m
        self.q=q

        print(f"y={m}x+{q}")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"y={self.m}x+{self.q}"

print(Line(3,2))
```

This will however print your output twice since it's running in the init method as well so that one can be removed.

As stated in my comment above, when you create an object from a class, it runs your **init** method if one exists. Since your **init** method contained a print function it printed that, however since you also printed the object itself it attempted to print some representation of it. Since none was defined, it printed python's default representation of an object.

If you need more detail. I can attempt and explain a little bit better.

Comment: It was perfect! Thank you fro the explaination!